# Convergence and metric - Proof?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, proof-verification

Let $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ be two sequences in a metric space $(P,d)$. Suppose $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ and $(y_n)$ converges to $y$. Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,y_n) = d(x,y)$

My proof:

> $ d(x,y) \le d(x,x_n) + d(x_n,y_n) + d(y_n,y) $ (properties of metric
>   space)
>
> $d(x,y) - d(x_n,y_n) \le d(x,x_n) + d(y_n,y)$
>
> $-d(x,x_n) - d(y_n,y) \le d(x_n,y_n) - d(x,y) \le d(x,x_n) + d(y_n,y)$
>
> $ \lvert d(x_n,y_n) - d(x,y) \rvert \le d(x_n,x) + d(y_n,y)$
>
> Because of $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ and $d(y_n,y) \to 0$ then $d(x_n,y_n) \to
>  d(x,y)$.
>
> And $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,y_n) = d(x,y)$

But I am not sure if this proof is right? Can anybody check it?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you getting the third line?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is almost right. You should be careful with two cases:

1. When $d(x,y)<d(x_n,y_n)$.
2. When $d(x_n,y_n)<d(x,y)$.

Because your third line is not clear, but you can get it using this two inequalities and the argument of the first line.